# SSAS Sum all but only show members in current dimension

Tags: mdx, ssas-2008

I have the following columns. (I can't post images at the moment so I hope this makes sense)

Rep Name | Appointment Count | Available Appointment Count

Rep 1    | 0 |  249

Rep 2    | 1 | 249

Rep 3 | 3 | 249

I am trying to create a calculated measure for 'Total Taken Appointments' in SSAS using the following Sum(All) formula in order to add all the appointments regardless of which representative has taken them. I am currently using the following

```
    SUM(
       (
          [Drug Rep].[Company Name].[All]
        , [Rep].[Rep Name].[All]
        , [Company Team].[Company Team Desc].[All]
       ) 
    ,[Measures].[Appointment Count])
```

The challenge I have is that when I do this it shows every single rep that is present in the database including representatives that do are not related to the total appointments for the customer. This ruins the vacancies calculations as I get a negative number because Total Appointments is 0.

Rep Name | Appointment Count | Available Appointment Count | Total_TakenAppoint | Vacant

Rep 1    | 0 |  249 | 152 | 97

Rep 2    | 1 | 249 | 152 | 97

Rep 3 | 3 | 249 | 152 | 97

Rep 4 |  | | 152 | -152

Rep 5 |  | | 152 | -152

Rep 6 |  | | 152 | -152

I would like it so that whilst summing all, it still only shows the rows that were visible in the first diagram and maintains the 249-152 relationship rather than producing all the '-152's'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding some sparsity to the measure via `null`:

```
IIF(
  (
     [Rep].[Rep Name].currentmember
     ,[Measures].[Appointment Count]
  )
 = 0
  ,NULL
  SUM(
   (
      [Drug Rep].[Company Name].[All]
    , [Rep].[Rep Name].[All]
    , [Company Team].[Company Team Desc].[All]
   ) 
  ,[Measures].[Appointment Count])
)
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for getting back to me, the challenge is that the first sum does not equal 0, it equals the total. Originally when I have the dimension with only the 'appointment count' measure showing, it has 2 reps for example. And then when I add this, will show 23 reps all with 23 next to them. I want it to show 23 but only next to the original two that were showing?

Comment: @LiamButler I think I now understand but could you add a couple of screenshots of 'current results' and 'desired results'  to your original post. I think we can just edit my current script to do what you want - keep the `iif` construct. I've edited script.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question to include some tables, I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @LiamButler I amended my script - does this help.

Comment: It worked! That is perfect! The only thing I think we lost a 'sum' after the IIF in the back and forth. Thanks very much fro your help!

Comment: @LiamButler glad it helped: the braces/brackets `(...)` form a `tuple` so the `SUM` probably isn't needed - I deliberately left that out - does it error without `SUM`?